# Как удалить изображение если его сторона меньше заданной

Tags: python, python-3.x, файлы, pil

Есть папка с кучей картинок в формате jpg (более 10000 штук). Часть из них очень маленькие. Хочу написать программу, которая будет удалять картинки маленького формата, по заданным параметрам. 
Пока вариант такой, но он выдает ошибку дойдя до os.remove(path). В чем причина и как это исправить? Или подскажите другой вариант решения.

```
from PIL import Image
import os


directory = r'C:\Python works\Foto\ff'
files = os.listdir(directory)


s = 0
for i in files:
    if i.endswith('.jpg'):
        path = r'C:\Python works\Foto\ff\{}'.format(files[s])
        im = Image.open(path)
        width, height = im.size
        if width <= 100 or height <= 100:
            print("Найдено изображение {}".format(i))
            try:
                os.remove(path)
            except:
                print('Error')
            print('Удалено')
        s += 1
```

Comment: Так ошибка  какая? Не проблема доступа ли?

Comment: File "new.py", line 18, in <module>
    os.remove(path)
PermissionError: [WinError 32] Процесс не может получить доступ к файлу, так как
 этот файл занят другим процессом: 'C:\\Python works\\Foto\\ff\\f-16036931601129
8Prod2122199sq2122199.jpg'

Comment: И почему вы тут берете файл по индексу `s`? `path = r'C:\Python works\Foto\ff\{}'.format(files[s])`. Допустим в папке 3 файла - Jpg, png, jpg, так когда `i` будет у вас на третьем файле, `s` будет обращаться ко второму файлу

Comment: Да, не подумал... Переделаю

Answer (score 1):

Вы забыли закрыть изображение перед удалением

```
from PIL import Image
import os


directory = 'C:\\Python works\\Foto\\ff'
files = os.listdir(directory)


for i in files:
    if i.endswith('.jpg'):
        path = f'{directory}\\{i}'
        im = Image.open(path)
        width, height = im.size
        im.close()
        if width <= 100 or height <= 100:
            print(f'Найдено изображение {i}')
            try:
                print(path)
                os.remove(path)
            except:
                print(f'Error: {e}')
            print('Удалено')
```

Answer (score 1):

[@n1tr0xs](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1077320/211923) уже объяснил причину появления ошибки и как с ней бороться - я бы хотел предложить чуть более короткий и читаемый вариант:

```
from pathlib import Path      

def is_img_too_small(path, width=1000, height=1000):
    with Image.open(path) as im:
        size = im.size
    return size[0] < width or size[1] < height
```

удаляем все "*.jpg" файлы в директории, у которых хотя бы одна из сторон меньше 100:

```
p = Path(r"C:\Python works\Foto\ff")

_ = [f.unlink() for f in p.glob("*.jpg") 
     if is_img_too_small(f, width=100, height=100)]
```